# Why core profile is not working?

Tags: c, opengl

This code works fine with compatibility profile context version 4.3 but when I switch to core, nothing is drawn, even though all of the GL functions I've used are included in the core profile. Here's the main part of code

```
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glClearDepth(-1.d);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    vs= glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fs= glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    program= glCreateProgram();

    const char* vertex_shader_text=
        "#version 430 core\n"
        "in vec2 vPos;"
        "in vec3 vCol;"
        "out vec3 colour;"
        "void main() {"
        "colour = vCol;"
        "gl_Position = vec4(vPos, 1.0, 1.0);"
        "}";
    const char* fragment_shader_text=
        "#version 430 core\n"
        "in vec3 colour;"
        "out vec4 frag_colour;"
        "out vec4 frag_colour2;"
        "void main() {"
        "frag_colour = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);"
        "frag_colour2 = vec4(colour, 0.0);"
        "}";
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glBindAttribLocation(program,0,"vPos");
    glBindAttribLocation(program,1,"vCol");
    glBindFragDataLocation(program,0,"frag_colour2");

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    float vertices[] =
    {
        -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
        3.f-2.f*(float)sqrt(3.d), -1.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
        1.f, 2.f*(float)sqrt(3.d)-3.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f
    };
    GLuint vertex_buffer = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*) 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void*) (sizeof(float) * 2));

A:
    if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else return TRUE;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
    SwapBuffers(ghDC2);
    goto A;
```

Comment: goto!? That aside, what platform are you using, and where are you initializing your gl context? Do you just change the declaration in the shaders?

Comment: Also can you check for errors after you create your shaders to see if they compile ok.

Comment: I use windows 8, and the context creation is done inside the window procedure. I'll check for errors and tell you if any error happened

Comment: No sir. The glGetError() command returned GL_NO_ERROR which means no error has occurred.

Comment: Sorry, I checked the errors while running the compatibility context. I'll check again in core mode.

Comment: This time I got GL_INVALID_OPERATION error while running the old faulty code with core context. However I won't let it happen again out of this mistake as I've found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you create & bind a [vertex array object (VAO)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) before setting up your vertex attributes:

> A Vertex Array Object (VAO) is an OpenGL Object that stores all of the state needed to supply vertex data (with one minor exception noted below). It stores the format of the vertex data as well as the Buffer Objects (see below) providing the vertex data arrays. Note that VAOs do not copy, freeze or store the contents of the referenced buffers - if you change any of the data in the buffers referenced by an existing VAO, those changes will be seen by users of the VAO.

VAOs are **required** in Core contexts but optional in Compatibility.

Comment: Thank you sir. I added these 3 commands before enabling the attributes and generating buffer: GLuint vao; glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao); glBindVertexArray(vao); The problem is removed now. I had guessed that the vao might be the cause but I put those commands in the wrong place, "after" enabling the attribute arrays